# Regions in CSS like C# regions?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to define regions in CSS file just like regions in C#?

Like in C# you define regions as follows

```
#region My Region
//your code here
#endregion
```

My problem is I don't want to use separate CSS files for my asp.net project but I also want to organinze so I can define specific sections like one for Master Page CSS and one for FormUser and so forth so it is easy to troubleshoot when needed. Is it possible?

Comment: I personally use comments between "sections". Never really understood how `#region` made code cleaner, everywhere I've seen it used the code around it was awful, long  and bloated...

Comment: Checkout this post http://superuser.com/questions/158492/vs2010-extension-for-css-regions 

It's exists couple extensions to VS

Comment: @Blindy It is more organized per my perspective as I can minimize the code and focus on specific code to troubleshoot, easy to change sections also instead of scrolling up and down.

Comment: Comments, comments, comments. A big bold separator line (or two) is a pretty good visual aid for separating sections.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

You can use this for regions...works well to make collapsible regions

```
/*#region RegionName*/

/*#endregion RegionName*/
```

The RegionName is optional in endregion, you can also use

```
/*#region RegionName*/

/*#endregion */
```

Shortcut in VS2015 onwards for this Type `region`, `[Esc]`, `[Tab]`.  Credits for shortcut to [Dush](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1068538/dush).

Comment: I must say this is a lot accurate answer to the question. But I have a question. Does Visual Studio have this feature built-in? From which version on? 2005, 2008, 2010?

Comment: Blast from the past, but thanks... helps me tidy up my CSS a lot

Comment: There is a code snippet for doing this, just type region and `Esc` then `tab`. It will add the code block. (In VS 2015 when you type region intellisense will replace it with rect, therefore you need to press `Esc` and then press `tab`. )

Comment: Although ending RegionName is not necessary, it is much helpful when you have lot of code and see what the ending region name is. Visual Studio shortcut(snippet) doesn't add ending RegionName. But your answer is more accurate and practically useful.

Comment: Re: @Dush Instead of Esc you can also double tap Tab. At least in VS 2013.

Comment: region + single tap of Tab  in VS 2017.    
  I wish it would add name part to #endregion.

Answer (score 11):

Type `region` and press `tab` you will get the following

```
/*#region name */

/*#endregion */
```

where you can edit the `name` to give the region a name of your choice.

Comment: Excellent shortcut, but In VS 2015 when you type `region` intellisense will replace it with `rect`, therefore you need to press `Esc` and then press `tab`. Then it will work as you explained.

Comment: VS 2019 works as described by WAQ above (ie Type region and press tab).

Comment: @Dush Same in VS2022:  Type `region`, `[Esc]`, `[Tab]`

Answer (score 7):

You can't do regions, but you can always just use spacing and comments to add some organization if you like.

```
/*Layout rules*/
body{}
div{}
etc{}

/*Typography Rules*/
etc{}

etc...
```

Answer (score 5):

No there is no support for regions in CSS.

The usual approach is separating into different CSS files and then use a CSS minification tool for production releases that combines and minifies your CSS, i.e. see [minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) or [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/).

Answer (score 4):

You can add Regions to your CSS exactly as you describe by using a visual studio plugin called  ["Web Essentials" (this is the VS2012 link, but earlier versions are available)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6)

Then you can simply add regions in your CSS by doing this :

```
/*#region Footer 
---------------------------------------------------- */
.footerHyperlinks{
  decoration:none;
}
/*#endregion*/
```

In conjunction with the keyboard shortcut (ctrl+M, ctrl+L) this for me is invaluable. as it instantly reduces your huge, long page that you have to scroll through MUCH, MUCH quicker.
Hope that helps you out !!

Answer (score 2):

You should use different CSS files and move them into 1 file while building your application. There are special tools for this that do just that as this is the only way.

Comment: That is nice didn't think of that  +1

Answer (score 1):

Use type of Media Query! this is too late to answer but I did this for grouping my code and it working perfectly for me

```
@media all /*'Global Settings'*/{
    body {
       background: red;
       padding-bottom: 120px;
    }
}

@media all /*'Header Settings'*/{
  .add-to-cart-header {
     height: 66px;
     background: #f7f7f7;

  }
}
```